# Debugs using Wifi using Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, barcode

I'm using an external IPC device for barcode scanning in my application.

So I need a way to debug the application using the Wi-Fi/Bluetooth.

Visual Studio has an option to Debug over Wi-Fi but I can't any option to connect to device or debug using Wi-Fi.

Any one has any idea how to do that?

Comment: Enable the `Debug over Wifi` option, the launch a debug session of the application while still connected to the USB cable so it can install/launch the app, once it starts, unplug the usb cable and plugin your scanner.

Comment: I did it.
I am connecting to Mac agent but when I am disconnecting the plug the app freezes.
Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

For first time connect device using data cable and follow following step

XCode -> Window > Devices and Simulators -> Connect via network checkbox 
make enable

Remove Data cable and check device name in project and project run again

**Note** : Make sure device and mac both are connect with same wifi

For reference check 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/wireless-deployment?tabs=vsmac